# Href to email not working in contact form, any tips?

Tags: php, html, css

i am trying to send an email to myself to test if the contact form works, but do not recieve any data on my end, nothing in mail inbox. any tips to where I am going wrong? cheers

https://jsfiddle.net/hne3j8z9/

> PHP

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/"; "upload-saves.php"
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}


// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}


// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}


// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "docx" && $imageFileType != ".pdf"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}


// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
}  else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

> HTML

```
<form action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi" method="post">
<div>
   <h2>Bewerbungsformular</h2>
   <label for="name">Vorname*</label>
   <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
</div>
   <div>
   <label for="mail">Nachname*</label>
   <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email">
</div>
   <div> 
   <label for="msg">E-Mail*</label>
   <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
</div>  
   <div>
   <label for="msg">Telefon*</label>
   <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
</div> 
   <div>
   <label for="msg">Arbeitsbeginn ab*</label>
   <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
</div>
   <div> 
   <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p>Lebenslauf und Beilagen</p>
   <div class="image-upload">
   <label for="file-input">
   <img src="upload.png"/>
</label>
   <input id="file-input" type="file"/>
</form>      
</div>
   <div class="button">
   <a href="mailto:example@email.com"></a> 
   <button type="submit">Send your message</button>
</div>
</form>
   <div class= swiss>
   <img src="swissstaffing_sqs_logo_cmyk.png" /> 
</div>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Please read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is just an HTML, where is the script to send email? Like code written in .NET, PHP, Python, Ruby, Java....

Comment: Show back-end code

Comment: you have close `<form>` tag twice

Comment: cheers guys, added it now. sorry just woke up haha

Comment: gona try that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get any data send to your own email as `mailto` will open your default mailprogram and prepare a new blank email to send.

[More details on mailto here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/)

If you want to send an email with post data from your form to yourself, you should do it with php, and change the recepient to your own email address...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options, follow either one

1. Add some text in the `a` tag like `<a href="mailto:alexjames.willi@gmail.com">Mail Me</a>` or `<a href="mailto:alexjames.willi@gmail.com">alexjames.willi@gmail.com</a>`
2. Add width,height,background and `display:inline-block` to the `a` tag like `<a href="mailto:alexjames.willi@gmail.com" style="width:100px; height:100px; display:inline-block"></a>`